# Matrix Inequality: $A^\top B A \preccurlyeq B$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-equations

Consider $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $A$ invertible, $B \succ 0$.

Say if the following holds:
$$ A^{- \top} B A^{-1} \preccurlyeq B \ \Longleftrightarrow \ B \preccurlyeq A^\top B A. $$

I do not know if I can multiply the LHS by $A^\top$ on the left and by $A$ on the right. For sure this is fine if $A = a I$, $a \neq 0$.

Comment: $B \succ 0$ means that $B$ is positive definite, i.e. $B = B^\top$ and $B$ has positive eigenvalues.

I tried to say that: (i) the claim is true for $B = I$; (ii) $B = C^{-\top} C^{-1}$ for some $C \succ 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint.* Back to the basics. $P\succeq Q$ means $P-Q\succeq0$, i.e. $x^\ast(P-Q)x\ge0$ for every vector $x$.

Comment: So I guess it is true that with $x = A y$, $x$ spans all $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $y$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @Adam Yes, the correspondence between $y$ and $x=Ay$ is bijective.